# how to make one label turn green color if a only one number is matched

Tags: c#

[image]

Mine is on the right side and won't do any colors only if I have all 3 matched

```
while (AttemptNumber <= 999)
{
    AttemptNumber = AttemptNumber + 1;   //ALT that i m not going to use : AttemptNumber++

    myString = "Attempt #" + AttemptNumber.ToString();

    myRandom1 = myRandomObj.Next(0, 9);
    myRandom2 = myRandomObj.Next(0, 9);
    myRandom3 = myRandomObj.Next(0, 9);

    random1Label.Text = myRandom1.ToString();
    random2Label.Text = myRandom2.ToString();
    random3Label. Text = myRandom3.ToString();

    AttemptsLbl.Text = AttemptNumber.ToString("#,##0");

    if (myRandom1 == myNum1 && myRandom2 == myNum2 && myRandom3 == myNum3)
    {
        // random label color changing for the label to green if matched
        random1Label.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
        random2Label.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
        random3Label.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;

        //we have match for all 3 digits = winner!
        myString = myString + " SUCCESS: " + myNum1 + myNum2 + myNum3 + " vs " + myRandom1 + myRandom2 + myRandom3;

        MessageBox.Show(" Match Found for All 3 Digits - it took " + AttemptNumber + " tries! ");

        Listbox.Items.Add(myString);

        matchFound = true;
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        //we dont have a match

        myString = myString + " Failed: " + myNum1 + myNum2 + myNum3 + " vs " + myRandom1 + myRandom2 + myRandom3;

        random1Label.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
        random2Label.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
        random3Label.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;

        Listbox.Items.Add(myString);      
    }
```

Like the pic displays I only want one color green to be matched or two if two digits are matched. How to make one label turn green color if a only one number is matched?
How to make a label turn green color if only one its matched not all three at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly. I guess this is what you are looking for.

1. Reset all label background color to grey on every iteration
2. Conditionally display background of each label only if that particular digit matches.

   ```
    while (AttemptNumber <= 999)
   {
      //Reset the Background Color for every Iteration
     random1Label.BackColor = Color.Grey;//Initial Background color
      random2Label.BackColor = Color.Grey;//Initial Background color
      random3Label.BackColor = Color.Grey;//Initial Background color  



     AttemptNumber = AttemptNumber + 1;   //ALT that i m not going to use : AttemptNumber++

   myString = "Attempt #" + AttemptNumber.ToString();

       myRandom1 = myRandomObj.Next(0, 9);
       myRandom2 = myRandomObj.Next(0, 9);
       myRandom3 = myRandomObj.Next(0, 9);

       random1Label.Text = myRandom1.ToString();
       random2Label.Text = myRandom2.ToString();
       random3Label. Text = myRandom3.ToString();

       AttemptsLbl.Text = AttemptNumber.ToString("#,##0");

       if (myRandom1 == myNum1 && myRandom2 == myNum2 && myRandom3 == myNum3)
       {

           // random label color changing for the label to green if matched

          random1Label.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
          random2Label.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
          random3Label.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;

           //we have match for all 3 digits = winner!

           myString = myString + " SUCCESS: " + myNum1 + myNum2 + myNum3 + " vs " + myRandom1 + myRandom2 + myRandom3;





           MessageBox.Show(" Match Found for All 3 Digits - it took " + AttemptNumber + " tries! ");


           Listbox.Items.Add(myString);

           matchFound = true;
           break;


        }
            else
        {

           //we dont have a match

           myString = myString + " Failed: " + myNum1 + myNum2 + myNum3 + " vs " + myRandom1 + myRandom2 + myRandom3;
        if (myRandom1 == myNum1)
           random1Label.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
        if (myRandom2 == myNum2)
            random2Label.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
        if (myRandom3 == myNum3)
           random3Label.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;

          Listbox.Items.Add(myString);      


    }
   ```

Comment: yes thank you so much @Venkatesh Muniyandi yes you know it good i wish i was that good at stuff i struggle with the easy stuff but thank you so much your a life saver